# Diet and compound exercises for mass gain

Tags: strength-training

Im 5'11" and weighs 65kg, age is 25.
I regularly hit gym.After a 20 minutes warm-up session, I do the concentrated exercises chest(monday), lats(tuesday) and so on. I follow the below diet:

Morning:
*BCAA (ON - gold)- post workout
*2 bananas, few dry fruits, milk (1 glass), two eggs

Afternoon:
*Roti (made of wheat flour), sometimes rice with dal
* 1 banana

Evening:
* 2 boiled eggs
* 1 fruit juice

Night:
* Chicken & rice

With the above diet and physical activity, I have gained around 4kgs in 1.5months.
I want to put on more weight with nice body shape.Please comment.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Putting on 4kg of muscle in 1.5 months sounds like **too much, too fast** to me. It may not be what you want to hear, but you ought to take it slower and aim to put on nothing but clean, lean muscle mass. You can always put on more *weight*. Sure, just eat more. Pretty simple, right? The sky's the limit.

It won't give you a nice body shape, though. *Weight* doesn't mean *muscle*.

If you put on weight too fast it's going to be a lot of fat. The body can only manufacture about [0.5-1kg of muscle per month](http://www.muscleforlife.com/how-much-muscle-can-you-build-naturally/). After that, any weight you gain is just fat.

This is a long term process. Be the tortoise. Slow and easy is the best way to win the race. Don't try to put on more than **1kg/month**.

Answer (score -1):

Actually if you gained 4kg with this, you can follow it until you stop gaining weight. At this time you can add some carbs (oats in morning, ...) until you gain more weight.

Comment: I would like to increase the mass gain rate. I regularly do 5 different kinds of isolation exercises (one muscle each day- 5days a week).

Comment: I would like to know more on 'adding the carbs'. I see that my appetite doubled these days (sometimes there is deficiency in my intake due to my work)

Comment: @Feroz your rate will never be so big than the first/second year of bodybuilding, you can gain 20kg in those years but if you keep that rate, you'll be really fat like those powerlifters. is that your goal ?

Comment: @Feroz your diet is nice but how much carbs do you eat per meal ? because you actuall don't eat that much carb. Each people has his habbits and mine is eating carb in each meal, 6 AM, 9 AM, 12AM, 15PM, 19PM...

Comment: As per my diet, below is the carb:

Comment: 8 AM: Dry fruits - dates,etc, milk; 13 PM: Wheat flour, pulses, biscuits; 20 PM: few. Can you suggest me the carb intake (I do not have a facility to cook)

Comment: @Feroz A simple exemple : oats ! You mix oats with water/milk/juice (you can also add cinnamon power for giving an extra taste ;O )